# Tree Construction with pointers

Tags: c++, tree

I'm trying to create a function that inserts a key struct into a tree.  The function sets the root correctly, but does not set the branches when called again with another key. Here is the code:

tree.h:

```
class tree{

    key *tree_root;

public:
    tree();
    //Constructor

    void treedestroy(key *root);
    //Tree destructor helper

    ~tree();
    //Destructor

    void insert(key* root, key *newkey, int disc);

};
```

insert function from tree class:

```
void tree::insert(key *root, key *newkey, int disc){
    if (root == NULL){
        root = newkey;
        return;
    }
    if (newkey->cord[disc] <= root->cord[disc])
        insert(root->left, newkey, (disc+1)%4);
    else if (newkey->cord[disc] > root->cord[disc])
        insert(root->right, newkey, (disc+1)%4);
}
```

I'm a little inexperienced with C++ pointers and was wondering how I could fix this code so that it will fill the tree correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about your approach here, but to help get you on your feet, it would help to use a function signature of:

```
void insert(key*& root, key *newkey, int disc);
```

This passes the root pointer by reference, which means that changes made inside the function will "stick" to the variable you passed in.

Your function as it stands modifies a function-local variable, without those changes propagating.

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/PtrToPtr.aspx) is a balanced and quick read on passing by reference (I can't say if it's the best - it was just the first decent one I found)

Answer (score 0):

1. If on the first call newkey is null, root will stay null.  Make sure method call is correct.
2. I would put an else rather than an else if.  If it is a binary tree it is either equal, greater, or less than.
3. Does it get into Insert_helper or not?  Why did you not include it, seems important?  I would guess it is getting at least that far.

Comment: Sorry that is supposed to be insert not insert_helper, and no it's not making it to insert.  If I pass in tree_root as root it is always null and sets root to newkey, but not tree_root.

Answer (score 0):

```
root = newKey;
```

This do not modify actual root. It just modify function argument which is a copy of pointer you specify when call intsert function.

Correct version would looks something like this:

```
private:
void tree::insert_helper( key **root, key *newkey, int disc ) {
  if ( (*root) == NULL ) {
     *root = key;
  } else if (newkey->cord[disc] <= root->cord[disc]) {
     insert_helper( &((*root)->left), newkey, (disc+1)%4 );
  } else {
     insert_helper( &((*root)->right), newkey, (disc+1)%4);
  }
}

public:
void tree::insert( key *newKey, int disc ) {
    insert_helper( &tree_root, newkey, disc );
}
```

Also you have to be sure that 'key' constructol set NULL for left and right. And tree constructor should set NULL for tree_root